# 2 pontos simples no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google

Se eu crio um ponto no Google Maps assim:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.457122, -52.197458);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng
  };



 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Hello</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'Hello World '+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var image = 'pin.png';  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Hello'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
```

É possível na mesma função criar mais 1 ponto?

Tenho que fazer outra função?

Como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
</html>


      <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```